# Uploading .csv file from Mac - PHP

Tags: php, macos, excel, csv

I ran into an issue earlier today with uploading a `.csv` file created from a Mac vs a PC through Microsoft Office Excel.  Heres the issue:

We have a `.csv` file that contains 2 data columns.  One for names and one for extensions.  You take this file and upload it into our server that enables us to use it for other things.  Heres the problem though, when uploading a new `.csv` file from a Mac, for some reason the program can't format correctly.

File Data Example:

```
Names | Extensions
Kevin | 109
James | 098
```

Uploaded from a PC and how program reads it:

```
Array ( [0] => Name [1] => Ext )
```

*This is correct because the first row is simply the names of what they contain

Uploaded from a Mac and how program reads it:

```
Array ( [0] => Name [1] => Ext Dave [2] => 209 Jose [3] => 140 )
```

Obviously there is a formatting issue between the two and I am not sure how to fix it.

Suggestions, ideas?

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note from the docs for [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

> If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.

**EDIT**

You can enable this at runtime using

```
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
```

Comment: Can I just enable that within the .PHP file or in configurations?